# How to trim a file extension from a String in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, replace, substring, substr, indexof

For example, assuming that `x = filename.jpg`, I want to get `filename`, where `filename` could be any file name (Let's assume the file name only contains [a-zA-Z0-9-_] to simplify.).

I saw `x.substring(0, x.indexOf('.jpg'))` on [DZone Snippets](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4060), but wouldn't `x.substring(0, x.length-4)` perform better? Because, `length` is a property and doesn't do character checking whereas `indexOf()` is a function and does character checking.

Comment: See: [Regular expression to remove a file's extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818310/regular-expression-to-remove-a-files-extension) and see also: [How can i get file extensions with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190852/how-can-i-get-file-extensions-with-javascript)

Comment: Pretty much the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991608/find-base-name-in-url-in-javascript. And unless you do one heck of a lot of these, worrying about efficiency is Premature Optimisation.

Comment: In the age of ES6, also see the [Path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module – in case you are using nodejs or a proper transpilation

Answer (score 299, accepted):

If you know the length of the extension, you can use `x.slice(0, -4)` (where 4 is the three characters of the extension and the dot).

If you don't know the length @John Hartsock [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4250408/9647762) would be the right approach.

If you'd rather not use regular expressions, you can try this (less performant):

```
filename.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')
```

Note that it will fail on files without extension.

Comment: I like this solution the best. It's clean, and I can use it cause I know the file extension is always `.jpg`. I was looking for something like Ruby's `x[0..-5]`, and `x.slice(0, -4)` looks great! Thanks! And thank you to everyone else for all the other robust alternatives provided!

Comment: this is not the optimal solution, please check other solutions below.

Comment: And if you're not 100% sure about the length of the extension, then don't this: `"picture.jpeg".slice(0, -4)` -> "picture."

Comment: This is dangerous solution, cause you don't really know the length of the format.

Comment: "If you know the length of the extension" It's been decades since this was an acceptable assumption to make. Don't use this anymore.

Comment: @Alexander Sorry to reply so late, but this is a perfectly acceptable solution in situations where you know the length of the extension, and those situations DO exist despite what you may think. In my case I'm filtering out all files that don't end with ".js" so it's not like I'm going to somehow get a different extension length anyway.

Comment: Not working on files without extension. gave a hard time detecting this bug at work.

Comment: `filename.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.') || filename` works even for files without extension.

Answer (score 648):

Not sure what would perform faster but this would be more reliable when it comes to extension like `.jpeg` or `.html`

```
x.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")
```

Comment: You probably want to also disallow / as a path separator, so the regexp is /\.[^/.]+$/

Comment: This works for any length of file extension (.txt or .html or .htaccess) and also allows for the file name to contain additional period (.) characters. It wouldn't handle eg .tar.gz due to the extension itself containing a period. It's more common for a file name to contain additional periods than a file extension. Thanks!

Comment: @Vik There's a difference between the 'right answer' and the accepted answer. An accepted answer is just the answer that was helpful for the one who asked the question.

Comment: I suppose that there may be issues with the Windows platform because there can be back slashes. So the regexp should be /\.[^/\\.]+$/.

Comment: @John Hartsock, I'm trying to use this with Adobe Extendscript and it's giving me a syntax error message and highlighting the ]+$ part. I think the ] is causing the problem. Does anyone know a workaround for this? I'm using it to append a string to the end of a file name before its extension so I can export graphics from an InDesign document.

Comment: @nollaf126 sounds like you need to escape the ]

Comment: What does `[^/.]` mean?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen here is a great tool for you to help answer your question https://regexr.com/

Comment: @ElgsQianChen the stackoverflow answer you found to your problem uses regex, now you have two problems. http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247

Comment: Does not handle cases where the string does not contain an extension.

Comment: How does a answer with no explanation get hundreds of ups?

Answer (score 609):

In **node.js**, the name of the file without the extension can be obtained as follows.

```
const path = require('path');
const filename = 'hello.html';
    
path.parse(filename).name;     //=> "hello"
path.parse(filename).ext;      //=> ".html"
path.parse(filename).base; //=> "hello.html"
```

Further explanation at **Node.js** [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_path) page.

Comment: This answer is pretty restricted to server-side node. If you try to use this in react code, it doesn't seem to import.

Comment: if you want to remove an extension from a path including the directories, you can do `var parsed = path.parse(filename)` followed by `path.join(parsed.dir, parsed.name)`.

Comment: Another possibility is `let base = path.basename( file_path, path.extname( file_path ) )`.

Answer (score 139):

`x.length-4` only accounts for extensions of 3 characters.  What if you have `filename.jpeg`or `filename.pl`?

EDIT:

To answer... sure, if you always have an extension of `.jpg`, `x.length-4` would work just fine.

However, if you don't know the length of your extension, any of a number of solutions are better/more robust.

`x = x.replace(/\..+$/, '');`

OR

`x = x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf('.'));`

OR

`x = x.replace(/(.*)\.(.*?)$/, "$1");`

OR (with the assumption filename only has one dot)

```
parts = x.match(/[^\.]+/);
x = parts[0];
```

OR (also with only one dot)

```
parts = x.split(".");
x = parts[0];
```

Comment: **??** You can have a filename ex: "summer.family.jpg" in that case **split('.')[0]** will return only a partial file name. I would remove that one from the answer, or clearly state underneath the issue for that example. @basarat ...

Comment: Something I do frequently regarding part splits: `var parts = full_file.split("."); var ext = parts[parts.length-1]; var file = parts.splice(0,parts.length-1).join(".");`

Comment: x.split(".") should not even be considered an answer. I know I use a '.' in almost all of my file naming conventions, i.e. 'survey.controller.js', or 'my.family.jpg'.

Comment: @Lee2808: Hence the warning of only one dot.  This is simply meant to show that there are a number of approaches, depending on the application.  I would certainly use one of the other methods in almost all cases.

Comment: `x = x.substr(0, x.lastIndexOf('.'));` - you probably meant `x = x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf('.'));`?

Comment: @tborychowski When the first parameter is 0, `substr` and `substring` do the same thing.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745515/what-is-the-difference-between-substr-and-substring

Comment: "it works for this case" isn't always the same as "it's correct implementation" :-) `substring`'s second parameter is `indexEnd`, `substr` takes `length`, so IMO `substring` fits better here.

Comment: Ah, I was actually about to argue the same point until I realized that, yes, I have them backwards.  So, yes, fair point.  Why javascript uses 2 functions that are easily confused is beyond me.

Comment: `x = x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf('.'));` is my choice. Thank you!

Answer (score 78):

I like this one because it is a one liner which isn't too hard to read:

```
filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.')) || filename
```

Comment: I think this one is the best because it's really easy to understand

Answer (score 53):

You can perhaps use the assumption that the last dot will be the extension delimiter.

```
var x = 'filename.jpg';
var f = x.substr(0, x.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

If file has no extension, it will return empty string. To fix that use this function

```
function removeExtension(filename){
    var lastDotPosition = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (lastDotPosition === -1) return filename;
    else return filename.substr(0, lastDotPosition);
}
```

Comment: Warning, this fails if there happens to be no filename extension.  You're left with an empty string.

Comment: Shorter version that accounts for no dots. `var f = x.substr(0, x.lastIndexOf('.')) || x;` This works because an empty string is falsy, therefore it returns x.

Comment: `String.prototype.substr()` is deprecated. Please use `String.prototype.slice()` or `String.prototype.substring()` instead. Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/string/substr).

Answer (score 23):

In Node.js versions prior to 0.12.x:

`path.basename(filename, path.extname(filename))`

Of course this also works in 0.12.x and later.

Comment: The [`path.parse` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250364/how-to-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-javascript/31615711#31615711) is simpler.

Answer (score 16):

I don't know if it's a valid option but I use this:

```
name = filename.split(".");
// trimming with pop()
name.pop();
// getting the name with join()
name.join('.'); // we split by '.' and we join by '.' to restore other eventual points.
```

It's not just one operation I know, but at least it should always work!

UPDATE: If you want a oneliner, here you are:

`(name.split('.').slice(0, -1)).join('.')`

Comment: It should not be name.join('') but name.join('.'). You split by dot but join by comma, so `hello.name.txt` returns `hello, name`

Comment: filename.split(".").shift();

Answer (score 13):

This works, even when the delimiter is not present in the string.

```
String.prototype.beforeLastIndex = function (delimiter) {
    return this.split(delimiter).slice(0,-1).join(delimiter) || this + ""
}

"image".beforeLastIndex(".") // "image"
"image.jpeg".beforeLastIndex(".") // "image"
"image.second.jpeg".beforeLastIndex(".") // "image.second"
"image.second.third.jpeg".beforeLastIndex(".") // "image.second.third"
```

Can also be used as a one-liner like this:

```
var filename = "this.is.a.filename.txt";
console.log(filename.split(".").slice(0,-1).join(".") || filename + "");
```

EDIT: This is a more efficient solution:

```
String.prototype.beforeLastIndex = function (delimiter) {
    return this.substr(0,this.lastIndexOf(delimiter)) || this + ""
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Another one-liner:

```
x.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".")
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have to process a variable that contains the complete path (ex.: `thePath = "http://stackoverflow.com/directory/subdirectory/filename.jpg"`) and you want to return just "filename" you can use:

```
theName = thePath.split("/").slice(-1).join().split(".").shift();
```

the result will be **theName == "filename"**;

To try it write the following command into the console window of your chrome debugger:
**`window.location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1).join().split(".").shift()`**

If you have to process just the file name and its extension (ex.: `theNameWithExt = "filename.jpg"`):

```
theName = theNameWithExt.split(".").shift();
```

the result will be **theName == "filename"**, the same as above;

### Notes:

1. The first one is a little bit slower cause performes more
   operations; but works in both cases, in other words it can extract
   the file name without extension from a given string that contains a path or a file name with ex. While the second works only if the given variable contains a filename with ext like filename.ext but is a little bit quicker.
2. Both solutions work for both local and server files;

But I can't say nothing about neither performances comparison with other answers nor for browser or OS compatibility.

working snippet 1: the complete path

```js
var thePath = "http://stackoverflow.com/directory/subdirectory/filename.jpg";
theName = thePath.split("/").slice(-1).join().split(".").shift();
alert(theName);
```

working snippet 2: the file name with extension

```js
var theNameWithExt = "filename.jpg";
theName = theNameWithExt.split("/").slice(-1).join().split(".").shift();
alert(theName);
```

working snippet 2: the file name with double extension

```js
var theNameWithExt = "filename.tar.gz";
theName = theNameWithExt.split("/").slice(-1).join().split(".").shift();
alert(theName);
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's another regex-based solution:

```
filename.replace(/\.[^.$]+$/, '');
```

This should only chop off the last segment.

Answer (score 7):

Simple one:

```
var n = str.lastIndexOf(".");
return n > -1 ? str.substr(0, n) : str;
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer strips the last extension part only (`.jpeg`), which might be a good choice in most cases.

I once had to strip all extensions (`.tar.gz`) and the file names were restricted to not contain dots (so `2015-01-01.backup.tar` would not be a problem):

```
var name = "2015-01-01_backup.tar.gz";
name.replace(/(\.[^/.]+)+$/, "");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var fileName = "something.extension";
fileName.slice(0, -path.extname(fileName).length) // === "something"
```

Comment: This is the only method so far that works for full paths: `path/name.ext` -> `paht/name` instead of just returning `name`, but I would rather do with with `fs.parse` although it is a bit more verbose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59576950/895245

Comment: I like this answer... to add to it: If you know the extension beforehand (or if the extension is a variable, then I find it more readable to say: `filename.slice(0, -'.zip'.length)` or `filename.slice(0, -extension.length)`.

Answer (score 6):

- A straightforward answer, if you are using Node.js, is the one in the first comment.
- My task was I need to delete an image in Cloudinary from the Node server and  I just need to get the image name only.
  Example:

```
const path = require("path")
const image=xyz.jpg;
const img= path.parse(image).name
console.log(img) // xyz
```

Answer (score 5):

**Node.js remove extension from full path keeping directory**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31615711/895245 for example did `path/hello.html` -> `hello`, but if you want `path/hello.html` -> `path/hello`, you can use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const path = require('path');
const filename = 'path/hello.html';
const filename_parsed = path.parse(filename);
console.log(path.join(filename_parsed.dir, filename_parsed.name));
```

outputs directory as well:

```
path/hello
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36099196/895245 also achieves this, but I find this approach a bit more semantically pleasing.

Tested in Node.js v10.15.2.

Answer (score 4):

Though it's pretty late, I will add another approach to get the filename without extension using plain old JS-

`path.replace(path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('.')), '')`

Comment: or `path.split('.').pop()` for one part file extensions

Comment: He was actually trying to get the file name, not the extension!

Answer (score 1):

We might come across filename or file path with multiple extension suffix. Consider the following to trim them.

```
text = "/dir/path/filename.tar.gz"    
output = text.replace(/(\.\w+)+$/,"")
```

result of output: "/dir/path/filename"

It solves the file extension problem especially when the input has multiple extensions.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 1):

This might help...

```js
const splitNameAndExtension = (fileName) => {
  const dotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");

  if (dotIndex === -1) {
    return { name: fileName, extension: "" };
  }

  const name = fileName.substring(0, dotIndex);
  const extension = fileName.substring(dotIndex + 1);

  return { name, extension };
};

const result = splitNameAndExtension("File A (1).txt");
console.log("result: ", result) // { name: "File A (1)", extension: "txt" }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where regular expressions come in handy! Javascript's `.replace()` method will take a regular expression, and you can utilize that to accomplish what you want:

```
// assuming var x = filename.jpg or some extension
x = x.replace(/(.*)\.[^.]+$/, "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to remove the extension from a filename, without using either regex or indexOf (indexOf is not supported in IE8). It assumes that the extension is any text after the last '.' character.

It works for:

- files without an extension: "myletter"
- files with '.' in the name: "my.letter.txt"
- unknown length of file extension: "my.letter.html"

Here's the code:

```
var filename = "my.letter.txt" // some filename

var substrings = filename.split('.'); // split the string at '.'
if (substrings.length == 1)
{
  return filename; // there was no file extension, file was something like 'myfile'
}
else
{
  var ext = substrings.pop(); // remove the last element
  var name = substrings.join(""); // rejoin the remaining elements without separator
  name = ([name, ext]).join("."); // readd the extension
  return name;
}
```

Comment: fails with `hello.tar.gz`, output is `hellotar`.

Comment: #AsifAli thanks you are right, I forgot to readd the file extension. I've updated the answer, I hope it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `path` to maneuver.

```
var MYPATH = '/User/HELLO/WORLD/FILENAME.js';
var MYEXT = '.js';
var fileName = path.basename(MYPATH, MYEXT);
var filePath = path.dirname(MYPATH) + '/' + fileName;
```

Output

```
> filePath
'/User/HELLO/WORLD/FILENAME'
> fileName
'FILENAME'
> MYPATH
'/User/HELLO/WORLD/FILENAME.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the regex to do that. It's short and easy to understand.

```js
for (const regexPattern of [
  /\..+$/,  // Find the first dot and all the content after it.
  /\.[^/.]+$/ // Get the last dot and all the content after it.
  ]) {
  console.log("myFont.ttf".replace(regexPattern, ""))
  console.log("myFont.ttf.log".replace(regexPattern, ""))
}

/* output
myFont
myFont
myFont
myFont.ttf
*/
```

The above explanation may not be very rigorous. If you want to get a more accurate explanation can go to [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to check

- [\..+$](https://regex101.com/r/B2pmXk/1/)
- [\.[^/.]+$](https://regex101.com/r/XPQ6mu/1)

Answer (score -1):

Another one liner - we presume our file is a jpg picture >> ex: var yourStr = 'test.jpg';

```
    yourStr = yourStr.slice(0, -4); // 'test'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x.slice(0, -(x.split('.').pop().length + 1));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

```
name.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')
```

that's all enjoy your coding...

Comment: This line of code is already included in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4250414/242933).

Answer (score -4):

I would use something like x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf('.')). If you're going for performance, don't go for javascript at all :-p No, one more statement really doesn't matter for 99.99999% of all purposes.

Comment: *"If you're going for performance, don't go for javascript at all"* - What else are you suggesting to use in web applications..?

Comment: He doesn't mention web applications.

Comment: This question was asked and answer was posted in 2010, 7 years ago, and JavaScript was pretty much used only in web applications. (Node was just born, it didn't even had a guide or NPM at that time)

Comment: ;-) Still, if performance matters on tasks like this, you might consider doing this on the backend and process the results on the frontend.