# how to map only parts of images source attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
var str = $.map($('.bimg'), (e) => $(e).attr('src')).join(',');
console.log(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class='bimg' src='gall/lorem.jpg' alt='img'>
<img class='bimg' src='gall/ipsum.jpg' alt='img'>
<img class='bimg' src='gall/dolor.jpg' alt='img'>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

**Result:**

```
gall/lorem.jpg,gall/ipsum.jpg,gall/dolor.jpg
```

**What I need:**

```
lorem,ipsum,dolor
```

Comment: Use this `var str = $.map($('.bimg'), (e) => $(e).attr('src').split('/')[1].split('.')[0]).join(',')` Or you can use regex `var str = $.map($('.bimg'), (e) => $(e).attr('src').match(/\/(.*)\.jpg/)[1])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trim a file extension from a String in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250364/how-to-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @0stone0 - is not just a trim of an extension - there is also folder part and also I need it using `map`

Comment: *Basic* extrapolating from @0stone0 's linked answer gives: `var x = $(e).attr('src'); x.substring(x.lastIndexOf('/')+1, x.lastIndexOf('.'))`

Comment: @freedomn-m - it's ok for one single image. I have a lot of them, and want to avoid loop

Comment: Put that inside the .map... where you have `$(e)`   https://jsfiddle.net/3Lcth4y0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regex` to get the image name from `src`.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var str = $.map($('.bimg'), (e) => $(e).attr('src').match(/\/(.*)\.jpg/)[1]).join(',')
  console.log(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class='bimg' src='gall/lorem.jpg' alt='img'>
<img class='bimg' src='gall/ipsum.jpg' alt='img'>
<img class='bimg' src='gall/dolor.jpg' alt='img'>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your map

```js
.split('/').pop().split('.').shift()
```

So we split on each `/` and use `pop()` to get the last one found

Then we'll split on each `.` and use `shift()` to get the first part

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var str = $.map($('.bimg'), (e) => $(e).attr('src').split('/').pop().split('.').shift()).join(',');
    console.log(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class='bimg' src='gall/lorem.jpg' alt='img'>
<img class='bimg' src='gall/ipsum.jpg' alt='img'>
<img class='bimg' src='gall/dolor.jpg' alt='img'>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

> lorem.jpg,ipsum.jpg,dolor.jpg