# base url using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get base url in jQuery?

Think I am in http://localhost/test/test_controller/test's js file then I want to get only

```
/test
```

or

```
http://localhost/test/
```

Comment: How do you define this "base" URL? Is it always the first directory in your URL, or do you have an application where this URL is defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find base name in URL in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991608/find-base-name-in-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You dont actually need to use jQuery. JavaScript provides this for you

```
var l = window.location;
var base_url = l.protocol + "//" + l.host + "/" + l.pathname.split('/')[1];
```

Comment: That won't give the "base" path as specified in the question though, will it? (Not that it's very clear what is wanted here in the first place.)

Comment: it gives http://localhost/test/test_controller/test

I only want to get

/test

or

http://localhost/test/

Comment: @Milina you need to define more clearly what exactly you want.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use this custom method :

```
// it will return base domain name only. e.g. yahoo.co.in
function GetBaseUrl() {
    try {
        var url = location.href;

        var start = url.indexOf('//');
        if (start < 0)
            start = 0 
        else 
            start = start + 2;

        var end = url.indexOf('/', start);
        if (end < 0) end = url.length - start;

        var baseURL = url.substring(start, end);
        return baseURL;
    }
    catch (arg) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the current page's url, check out the [link object](http://help.dottoro.com/ljwejnnp.php).

You'll probably want document.hostname or document.host.

If your looking for the hostname of a link inside the document, see [this conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420881/javascript-jquery-method-to-find-base-url-from-a-string)

Comment: dead link. please fix or delete