# JQuery ajax .load() to reference to the correct url

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax

I have a localhost with a few projects, so this project in VS2010 properties->web->use local IIS web server = 'localhost/project4/'. (I can't use the normal debug VS Development Server as some components won't work in my project) Anyhow, localhost is fine no big deal, so I go on coding.

Now, in ajax when I call .load('/Account/LogOn'); it gives me 'localhost/Account/LogOn' but what I really want is 'localhost/project4/Account/LogOn' because it is sitting in the project4 directory, not the root.

Any idea how to tell ajax I need that virtual directory prefix between domain name and the rest of the url?

EDIT --------------------------------------------

Thanks guys, combined with all your knowledge, I guess the best ways to do it are:

1. Include the js script into .cshtml server side and use "~/Account/LogOn/" let .net figure out the path.
2. Make a global var remove_me_debug_only_virtual_directory = "/project4/"; in js code. append it to the domain name. this way we don't have to pull .net into the water and write js code in .cshtml.
3. Move the project to localhost/ root if you can, in this case I can't, because other people at work wants to access this networked server and do demo.

Comment: Have you tried `.load('Account/LogOn');` (without the preceding `/`)?

Comment: @J Steen, I think tilda only works on server side like @Url.Content("~/Account/LogOn") in a .cshtml or .aspx? Doesn't seem to work in js file? I will end up having 'localhost/~/Account/LogOn' and .load() will not parse it for me?

Comment: @Anthony G, without preceding "/" would give more problem, say, u have an ajax LogOnPartial first time calling from Home/Index/ u will get 'localhost/project4/Account/logOn', good. but when you go to Account/Index/ call that LogOnPartial again, u will get 'localhost/project4/Account/Account/LogOn', repeated twice, which is no good.

Answer (score 3):

If your JS code is in an MVC cshtml file, use it like this:

```
.load('@Url.Action("LogOn", "Account")');
```

The proper URL will be placed in the concrete JS code.

Answer (score 2):

According to .net documents,

> Absolute and relative path references in a server control have the following disadvantages:
>
> Absolute paths are not portable between applications. If you move the application that the absolute path points to, the links will break.
>
> Relative paths in the style of client elements can be difficult to maintain if you move resources or pages to different folders.
>
> To overcome these disadvantages, ASP.NET includes the Web application root operator (~), which you can use when specifying a path in server controls. ASP.NET resolves the ~ operator to the root of the current application. You can use the ~ operator in conjunction with folders to specify a path that is based on the current root.

So as described above, using `~` will lead you to the root of your web project using asp:

```
 <asp:image runat="server" id="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/SampleImage.jpg" />
```

For more information go to: [Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

**Based on your update**: Possible duplicate of: [base url using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563876/base-url-using-jquery)

Where stated by @gregguida:

```
  var l = window.location;
  var base_url = l.protocol + "//" + l.host + "/" + l.pathname.split('/')[1];

  //all you need to do is work with l.pathname.split('/') to find what you need.
```

Comment: hmmm, as I mentioned above, Razor @Url.Content("~/Account/LogOn") or WebForm <asp:image id="img1" Url="~/Account/LogOn" runat="SERVER">, these are server side code. I am talking about js code ajax .load()...

Comment: Are you saying .load() does not execute your asp code before loading? because load() read content from server then returns the corresponding html.

Comment: sorry, my bad, I modified the title a bit now. I mean the .load() function in js JQuery one. Not the server side one.

Answer (score 1):

I am a java developer but the context is same in both case,
In your can follow the steps

1. Check the context of your server if root is **"/"** then you have to call something like,

   .load('/project4/Account/LogOn');
2. If your application is root and you can calling this request from itself then

   .load('Account/LogOn');

Comment: I thought about hard coding '/project4/' into the script, but isn't it a bit wrecky and hacky when I try deploy the project to a real domain or re-use the code in the future?

Comment: I java we use to use request.getConextPath for resolving such conflicts. You should have something like that in .net also