# Why won't this regex work in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I'm trying to get a regex to capture the base URL from a URL string. This

```
^(.+?[^\/:])(?=[?\/]|$)
```

works. [REGEX101](http://regex101.com/r/jG3kT8/1)

But when I try to use it within postgresql

```
regexp_replace(content_url,'^(.+?[^\\/:])(?=[?\\/]|$)', '\1')
```

it does not

Answer (score 1):

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/postgresql.html) gives this warning about the first '?'

> PostgreSQL is inconsistent in the way it handles lazy quantifiers in
>   regular expressions with alternation because it attempts to match the
>   longest alternative, instead of being eager and accepting the first
>   alternative that matches

and if you remove it, it seems to work, i.e `^(.+[^\/:])(?=[?\/]|$)`

however, if you're trying to parse the baseurl that regex won't work. Use this instead:

```
select regexp_replace('....', '^(.*:)//([a-z\-.]+)(:[0-9]+)?(.*)$', '\2')
```

Comment: `SELECT regexp_replace('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991608/find-base-name-in-url-in-javascript','^(.+[^\/:])(?=[?\/]|$)', '\1') AS content_url;` just gives me a box. Like a little "unknown character" box.

Comment: @thomas maybe it's the escaping, works here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cfab1/4/0

Comment: Can you provide another solution that will work with postgre?

Comment: `[Error Code: 0, SQL State: 2201B]  ERROR: invalid regular expression: invalid character range :(`

Comment: what version of postgres are you using?

Answer (score 0):

PostGreSQL has an interesting regular expression engine. It took me a while to figure out what be escaped and what needs to be double-escaped. The solution that worked for me is:

```
(regexp_matches(content_url,'(https?:\/\/\\w+(?:\\.\\w+)+)'))[1] AS content_url
```

Hope this can help someone.